# Routing Not Doing What I expect with MVC4 Routes in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've got two very simple routes.  One works and pass the first parameter (year) into the controller and the other send the parameter in as "text".  I just don't get it.

Below are my two routes I've defined. they seem identical to me in shape.

the controllers are just..

```
         public ActionResult Index(string year)...

        // SESSIONS
        routes.MapRoute("SessionRouteAll", "Session/{year}",
                  new
                  {
                      /* Your default route */
                      controller = "Session",
                      action = "Index",
                      year = currentYear
                  });

        // SPEAKERS
        routes.MapRoute("SpeakerRouteAll", "Speaker/{year}",
                  new
                  {
                      /* Your default route */
                      controller = "Speaker",
                      action = "Index",
                      year = currentYear
                  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had other issues here causing the problem.